# CDN performance degrading during load testing

Tags: performance

While load testing our website through Soasta we found that the API calls were performing consistently without any degrade in performance (thanks to larger Ec2's serving them and the Elastic Load Balancer who is balancing the load appropriately), but the CDN calls (we use Akamai) (js, css, images ) started slowing down after some time. The difference was as large as 10 times e.g. an image which usually takes 100 ms took 1 second on few instances. I am curious to find out what could lead to this, because if the image is already cached at nearest location then why would it get slow during the repeated download? could it be due to heavy TCP traffic congestion (due to load testing) to the requesting server.

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. Unfortunately, as currently stated your question is too broad to be answered. Either it has too many possible answers or a good answer would be too long for this format. Please [edit] your question and it will automatically start a reopen vote. You may find our [Question Checklist](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/292/33) helpful to improve your question. We would need to know a lot more about the environment and what was going on to provide any meaningful answers.

Comment: I have tried to put as much as i knew, unfortunately my knowledge about network behaviors is nascent so the question is more generic as I could only mention what I could think about. I am doing some research on my own and taking help of my CDN provider to identify where could the problem lie. Will update the question with answer if I find it or my with findings.

Comment: You haven't even provided the CDN service, so we can't even begin to know exactly how it operates to formulate an answer. If you have been doing research, you should probably know by now how that alone can make the question as phrased too broad as there are many CDN services that each operate in somewhat different ways (which they will all tell you is better than their competitors).

Comment: Centralized load-test could be hitting the same Akamai edge server and overloading it, though those static files should be cached in memory.  Your API calls going to origin probably have a load-balancer to spread the load out.  What you didn't indicate is how distributed the load test is and if the API calls also go through edge a hostname or direct to origin.

Comment: I was also suspecting that akamai might be having a static set of server serving the files and they may not be adding additional server when the load increases (may be they need the load to be consistent for some minimum duration before increasing the compute capacity) and our test might not be triggering their auto scaling algorithm. Have already asked about this to Akamai support but haven't heard anything from them so far.

Comment: The CDN tag was intended for service providers, not people who cache objects in a CDN.  Please talk directly to akamai

Comment: Can you identify which images?  Image type (jpg, png), are they loaded via AJAX?  Maybe try and narrow down that way?...